# How to Pass variable in wp_footer action?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I'm creating Elementor page builder widget. I'm not to interest add inline java-script. Im using " wp_footer " action. I want to pass variable inside `add_action/wp_footer/function() { $$$ here $$$$ }.`

There are no Java Scripts Error.

```
$var_1 = '100';
$var_2 = '200';

add_action( 'wp_footer', function() { 
<script>
   (function($) {
      'use strict';
          $('.id').numerator({
                easing: 'linear',
                duration: '<?= $var_1; ?>', 
                toValue:'<?= $var_2; ?>',
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those variables should not be inside the function? What about use global variables?

Answer (score 0):

this is not a good practice, but if this what you want, the code is below. The key is to handle everything as a string. If you use quotation marks you can catenate the variables easily.

```
$var_1 = '100';
$var_2 = '200';

add_action( 'wp_footer', function() { 

echo "<script>
 (function($) {
  'use strict';
     $('.id').numerator({
            easing: 'linear',
            duration: '$var_1', 
            toValue: '$var_2',
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>";
}
```